# setting variable in if statement, then told it's unassigned

Tags: c#

I want to initialize an array--I don't know how big it will be. then set it in a condition

so I've got:

```
string[] my_string;

if(x==2)
{
my_string=File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
}

string new_string=my_string[1];
```

It's telling me I've an unassigned local variable, because it's in the condition. How do I get around this?

Comment: What do you expect `my_string[1]` to be if `x == 3`?

Comment: right. I guess I just have to put all the rest of the code in the condition as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not Create a List instead and then utilize the File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")
also are you including the FilePath along with file.txt 
here is a free code snippet for you to use I use this alot when I want to load a TextFile into a List as one bulk load...

```
List<string> lstLinesFromFile = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(yourFilePath+ "file.txt"));
```

from there you can check in the debugger or add a quickwatch to lstLinesFromFile and see all the text that was loaded. each line from there will be accessed link ordinal so use a for loop or foreach loop

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure it has a value if `x` isn't `2`.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, if x is not equal to 2, then you have no values in your array, but you're still calling that array anyway. One thing you could do is move the `new_string` assingment inside the `if statement`. Of course, this may not be the best method if you have other values of `x` you watch to check against. If so, a `Switch..Case` might be better.

```
string[] my_string;
//set new_string to be empty for now
string new_string = String.Empty; 

if(x==2)
{
   my_string=File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
   //Make sure there are at least two elements
   if(my_string.Length >= 2)       
   //Get the second element of the array (remember, 0 is the first element)
      new_string = my_string[1];
}
```

Comment: Should also check if `my_string` contains at least 2 elements otherwise it access out of bounds.

Comment: I assumed that there were enough lines in the text for the example, but you're right. Updated :)